# c++ template syntax

Tags: c++, templates

How do I fix this syntax error?

```
struct A {
  template < typename T >
  void f () {}
};

template < typename C, typename U >
struct B {
  void g () {
    U::f < C > ();   // expected primary-expression before »>« token
  }
};

int main () {
  B<int,A> b;
  b.g ();
}
```

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`U` is a dependent type so you need to specify that `f` is a template member:

```
U::template f<C>();
```

This is still invalid when `U` is `A`, though, as `f` is not a `static` member of `A`.