# Compiler error when using integer as template parameter

Tags: c++, templates, dependent-name

What is wrong with the following piece of code?

```
template<typename X>
struct A {
        template<int N>
        int foo() const {
                return N;
        }
};

template<typename X>
struct B {
        int bar(const A<X>& v) {
                return v.foo<13>();
        }
};

#include <iostream>
using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main() {
        A<double> a;
        B<double> b;
        cout << b.bar(a) << endl;
        return 0;
}
```

Inside the function `B::bar` the compiler complains:

> error: invalid operands of types
>   ‘’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’

If A is not a template, everything compiles fine.

Comment: possible duplicate of [c++ template syntax](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3621719/c-template-syntax)

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Change `return v.foo<13>();` to `return v.template foo<13>();` because `foo` is a dependent  name and you need to mention that explicitly using `.template` construct.