# Disambiguator template keyword for a template member of a template: when exactly?

Tags: c++, templates

A question regarding template disambiguator was given here:

[template disambiguator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077110/template-disambiguator)

and in the answer we can read:

ISO C++03 `14.2/4`

> When the name of a member template specialization appears after . or -> in a postfix-expression, or after nested-name-specifier in a qualified-id, and the postfix-expression or qualified-id explicitly depends on a template-parameter (14.6.2), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template. Otherwise the name is assumed to name a non-template.

Now here comes my conrete example that I don't quite understand:

```
template <class T>
class Base {
  public:


  template <int v>
    static int baseGet() {return v;}

  class InnerA {
    public:

    template <int v>
      static int aget() {return v;}

  };

  class InnerB {
    public:
      typedef Base BaseType;
      typedef BaseType::InnerA OtherType;

      template <int v>
        static int baseGet() {return BaseType::baseGet<v>();} //(A)

      template <int v>
        static int aget() {return OtherType::aget<v>();} //(B)
  };
};
```

It obviously fails to compile. You need `template` in the line (B): `OtherType::template aget<v>();`.
However, both g++ (4.4.3) and clang++ (2.9) don't complain about the lack of `template` in the line (A). Why? `BaseType` depends on the type `T`, does it not? Is it a small depart from the standard by those compilers, or do I misunderstand something in the standard?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

They implement the C++0x specification, where `Base` is the *current instantiation*. And C++0x allows to omit `template` keyword in such a case. Since `BaseType` is a typedef for `Base`, when you say `BaseType`, that names the current instantiation too.

To quote the spec, since you seem to be interested in spec refs

> A name is a **member of the current instantiation** if it is [...]
>
> - A qualified-id in which the nested-name-speciﬁer refers to the **current instantiation** and that, when looked up, refers to at least one member of the current instantiation or a non-dependent base class thereof.

and

> A name refers to the **current instantiation** if it is [...]
>
> - in the definition of a [...] **nested class** of a class template, [...], **the injected-class-name** (Clause 9) of the class template or nested class

and (the modified 14.2/4 that you quoted)

> [...] or the nested-name-specifier in the qualified-id refers to a dependent type, but the name is not a member of the current instantiation (14.6.2.1), the member template name must be prefixed by the keyword template. [...]

---

Note: In C++03 your code is ill-formed because both `BaseType` and `OtherType` are dependent. The spec says:

> A type is dependent if it is [...]
>
> - a template parameter
> - a qualified-id with a nested-name-specifier which contains a class-name that names a dependent type
> - a template-id in which either the template name is a template parameter or any of the template arguments is a dependent type

(note that `Base` is equivalent to `Base<T>`, which is the base on which `Base` and `BaseType::InnerA` are dependent types).

Note that "explicitly depends" in your quote is a pre-standard term, and was gotten rid of fairly lately (I believe it was at December1996). It basically meant (in this context) a qualified-id in which the qualifier is dependent or a class member access (`a->x` / `a.x`) where the `a` was dependent. After "explicitly depends" was removed from the draft, it was still lurking around at some places, and even C++0x has still references to "explicitly depends" in a note at 14.6.2p2:

> the base class name `B<T>`, the type name `T::A`, the names `B<T>::i` and `pb->j` **explicitly depend** on the template-parameter.

Answer (score 1):

Because `OtherType` is a *nested* dependent name while `BaseType` is not a nested type to begin with.

You need to use `template` for *nested* dependent types.

The keywords here are:

- Dependent Type
- Nested Type

If a *type* is both, then you've to use *template*.

- `OtherType` is both dependent type (it depends on `T`) as well as nested type
- `BaseType` is only dependent type (it depends on `T`). Its not a nested type.

Comment: According to http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4103756/what-is-a-nested-name-specifier both `BaseType::` and `OtherType::` are nested-name-specifiers. The fact that you actually specify a namespace already within your scope does not matter... or?

Comment: @Cygnus: Types defined at namespace level are not called *nested* types.

Answer (score 0):

`BaseType` does depend on the type `T`- but so does `InnerB`. In effect, from the perspective of any code inside `BaseType<T>`, it does not depend on `T`.

Comment: Since I am inside of `Base<T>` and you say that it does not depend on `T` - then why do I need `template` in line (B)?

Comment: @CygnusX1: It's because you're accessing another inner class. Inner classes are treated very strangely in C++03 and the rules about them don't make much logical sense.