# Template keyword for dependent types in C++11

Tags: c++, templates

This is an even more in-depth follow-on to:
[this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6456636/disambiguator-template-keyword-for-a-template-member-of-a-template-when-exactly)

Consider the following code:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
 public:
  template <typename T2>
  const T2* DoSomething() { ... }
};

template <typename T>
class B : public A<T> {
 public:
  const int* DoSomethingElse() {
    return this->DoSomething<int>();  // Compiler wants 'template' keyword here:
 // return this->template DoSomething<int>();
  }
};
```

Why doesn't this compile? I understand that the relevant section of the standard is 14.2/4, but I'm not sure I understand the nuts and bolts of why this doesn't work. Can someone break down the wording in that section to explain why this doesn't work? Additionally, can you describe (generally) under what circumstances the template keyword can be omitted?

Note that in C++11 the following code *does* compile:

```
template <typename T>
class A {
 public:
  template <typename T2>
  const T2* DoSomething() { ... }
};

class B {
 public:
  scoped_ptr<A<int>> var_;

  const int* DoSomethingElse() {
    return var_->DoSomething<int>();
  }
};
```

What's the difference?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's because C++ is not a context-free grammar.

Normally, the compiler looks at previously declared symbols to decide whether the angle brackets in the token sequence `DoSomething`, `<`, `int`, `>` are relational operators or part of a template name.  Since this is a template, and it isn't yet known whether `A<T>` will be specialized, the compiler cannot rely on prior declarations in the symbol table and needs help from the programmer.

Answer (score 3):

Suppose you have this:

```
template <> class A<float>
{
    int DoSomething;
    // ...
};
```

Suddenly the expression `this->DoSomething < ...` means something very different. There's no way to determine what a given *name* means if it is a dependent name. That's why *you* have be explicit about whether a name is a variable, a typename or a template.

Comment: @ctta0s: No... I should have said "variable or function", though you can think of a function as a function pointer, which *is* a variable... in any case, you first have to know what sort of entity your token is supposed to be, and only *then* can you check whether it parses correctly. You don't infer the nature of a token from the best way you can parse it.