# Can C++ 17 handle nested variadic templates?

Tags: c++, variadic-templates, c++17

Consider the C++ 17 code below, which tests a set of enum values to see if another enum value is contained in that set:

```
enum Flag { val1, val2, val3, val4, val5 };

template<Flag arg> struct Value {
    template<Flag... set> struct IsIn {
        static constexpr bool value =
            static_cast<bool>(((set == arg) || ...));
    };
};
```

This works as intended:

```
bool x = Value<val4>::IsIn<val1, val2, val5>::value;
// x == false

bool y = Value<val2>::IsIn<val3, val2>::value;
// y == true
```

However, I wish to test if all of a set of values are contained within another set, like so:

```
template<Flag... args> struct Values {
    template<Flag... set> struct AreIn {
        static constexpr bool value =
            static_cast<bool>((Value<args>::IsIn<set...>::value && ...));
    };
};
```

The above does not compile on GCC 7.3 or Clang 5.0; they both give rather cryptic answers that give little insight into the problem. Given that parameter pack expansion in a template parameter list is allowed (as long as the template supports the expansion), I'm having a hard time figuring out why this isn't legal C++.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You've run into one of the most irritating problems in the C++ syntax: non-inferrable [dependent names](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/dependent_name).

When you do `Foo<Bar>::Baz<Quux>`, since `Foo<Bar>` is a dependent name, you must put the `template` keyword before `Baz` in order to prevent the parser from running off a cliff. Clang is *usually* quite good at explicitly telling you about this with a helpful error, but in some cases (like yours) it just explodes and says `Expected )` or something equally unhelpful.

For more information, see [this other question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10856077/template-keyword-for-dependent-types-in-c11)

So, all you have to do to fix your template, is add the `template` keyword on the dependent template invocation:

```
template<Flag... args>
struct Values {
    template<Flag... set>
    struct AreIn {
        static constexpr bool value =
            static_cast<bool>((Value<args>::template IsIn<set...>::value && ...));
    };
};
```

Note, also, that the `static_cast<bool>()` is redundant.

Comment: Ah, I'm familiar with that concept when using the `typename` keyword; didn't know about when to use the `template` keyword.  I fought this one for a few hours before giving up to ask here... thanks a ton!

Answer (score 4):

This solves your problem: replace

```
static_cast<bool>((Value<args>::IsIn<set...>::value && ... ))
```

by

```
static_cast<bool>((Value<args>::template IsIn<set...>::value && ... ))
```

Why is this? At the point of *parsing* the declaration of `AreIn`, the compiler can't know what possible types `Value<args>` might resolve to. Perhaps, at a later point in the file, you'd be going to declare a specialization of `Values` that does not contain a template subclass `IsIn` but rather a field of that name. Using the `template` keyword promises to the compiler that `IsIn` is expected to be *some* sort of template, so the following `<` ... `>` get parsed as template arguments, rather than comparison operators with `set...` and with `::value` (a variable in the global namespace), which would also make sense.

Of course, one could ask why the compiler does not wait till it knows that you are using `Values<val1, val2>`, for which there indeed is a templated subclass `AreIn<val1, val2, val5>` which has a static member `::value`. But parsing ahead and remembering a partially processed syntax tree is just how today's compilers work, and the standard makes the `template` hint mandatory for the above reasons.