# c++ compiler treats template syntax as '<' operator

Tags: c++, templates, compiler-errors

I'm trying to compile the following code:

```
struct A {
    template<int N> static void a() {}
};

template<> void A::a<5>() {}

template<class T>
struct B {
    static void b() {
        T::a<5>();
    }
};

void test() {
    A::a<5>();
    B<A>::b();
}
```

and compiler interprets `<` in `T::a<5>` as an operator `<`, resulting in error:

```
invalid operands of types ‘<unresolved overloaded function type>’ and ‘int’ to binary ‘operator<’
```

Is there any way to explicitly instantiate `T::a<5>` without compiler errors?
Thank you.

gcc version 4.5.1 20100924 (Red Hat 4.5.1-4) (GCC)

Comment: possible duplicate of [template disambiguator](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077110/template-disambiguator)

Answer (score 6):

Yes, change that line to:

```
T::template a<5>();
```

Compiler doesn't know if `T::a` is a function (because of its `template` nature). By mentioning `template`, you inform compiler explicitly. This question is asked many times, here is [one of them](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4077110/template-disambiguator).