# Why can I not call templated method of templated class from a templated function

Tags: c++, templates

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Confusing Template error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3786360/confusing-template-error)

I have a templated class with a templated method.
Now I have another function, with 2 template arguments creating the class with the first template argument and calling the function with the second.
Consider this example:

```
template<class S>
class A {
public:
    template<class T>
            T f1() {
                    return (T)0.0;
            }

};

template<class T,class CT>
void function() {
    A<T> a;
    a.f1<CT>(); // gcc error in this line
}
```

gcc gived me:

```
error: expected primary-expression before ‘>’ toke
```

in the line marked above. Why does this not work and how can I fix it?
Thanks!
Nathan

Comment: @ebo: ah thanks, and Johannes' example is so much more evil that anything I could ever come up with :)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

`A<T>` is a *dependent type* (i.e. it depends on the template parameter `T`), so you have to specify that you're referring to a template member:

```
a.template f1<CT>();
```

Answer (score 5):

You can, but you need to help the compiler.

Because `a` has a dependent type, the compiler cannot assume what `a.f1` refers to. It could be a type, a constant, a function... whatever.

Because the template syntax uses `<` it is easily confused with the `operator<`.

Therefore the Standard requires that you disambiguates the nature of elements within a dependent type. This applies both to:

- types, with the use of `typename`, such as `typedef typename A<T>::SomeType type;`
- functions, with the use of `template`, such as `a.template f1<CT>();`

It can be argued that since it is known that `CT` is a type, such a disambiguation is meaningless, but things get hairy when it involves functions being passed as type parameters.

For example `a.f1<CT()>();` can be interpreted either as:

- Compare `a.f1` and a default constructed `CT` using `operator<`
- Call `a.f1` with a `CT()` as template parameter

The C++ syntax is (for once) uniform and requires disambiguation in all cases.

A quality compiler will suggest to you the appropriate fix when it can makes sense of your construct.