# Instantiating a templated class from a templated member function of a not templated class

Tags: c++, templates

I have been trying to understand the working of the code for boost::any and tried writing the following code

```
class placeholder
{
public:
  virtual ~placeholder() {}
  virtual placeholder* clone() const=0;
};
//And this is the wrapper class template:

template<typename ValueType>
class holder : public placeholder
{
public:
  holder(ValueType const & value) : held(value) {}
  virtual placeholder* clone() const
  {return new holder(held);}

private:
  ValueType held;
};

//The actual type erasing class any is a handle class that holds a pointer to the abstract base class:

class any
{
  public:

    any() : content(NULL) {}

    template<typename ValueType>
      any( const ValueType  & value): content(new holder(value)) {}


    ~any()
    {delete content;}

    // Implement swap as swapping placeholder pointers, assignment
    // as copy and swap.

  private:
    placeholder* content;
};

int main( int argc, char ** argv ) {

  return 0;
}
```

When I try to compile the code I get the following error:

```
test.cxx: In constructor 'any::any(const ValueType&)':
test.cxx:33: error: expected type-specifier before 'holder'
test.cxx:33: error: expected ')' before 'holder'
```

The error above appears in the line

```
any( const ValueType  & value): content(new holder(value)) {}
```

I don't really understand why the type cannot be deduced here. I read [Why can I not call templated method of templated class from a templated function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6773786/why-can-i-not-call-templated-method-of-templated-class-from-a-templated-function) however was not able to solve my problem

Can someone please help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since `holder` is a template and C++ does [not deduce template parameters based on the constructor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/984394/why-not-infer-template-parameter-from-constructor), you must specify the template parameter when instantiating it in the constructor of `any`.

```
template <typename ValueType>
any( const ValueType  & value): content(new holder<ValueType>(value)) {}
```